# PySpark/python- I tried using for loop but it returns empty dataframe. How do I solve it?

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark

When I do it outside for loops the script works perfectly fine, but when I run in the for loop it gives out empty columns.

```
COUNTRY_LIST = ['MY','SG','LK','ID','BD','KH','PH','TH']

for country in COUNTRY_LIST:
    print('Begin '+country+'')
    # Begin filtering for country
    poi_co = poi_reference.filter(F.col('country') == '+country+')
    poi_ret = poi_co.filter(F.col('l1_name') == 'Retail')
    poi_final = poi_ret.dropDuplicates(['unique_id'])

    # Remove uneccesarry columns and generate input file and master file
    index = Window().orderBy(F.lit('A'))
    input_final = poi_final.withColumn("no", F.row_number().over(index))
    input_final = input_final.select(*['no',F.col('unique_id').alias('name'),'latitude','longitude','radius'])

    # Save Geofence input file
    output_path_geof = 's3a://a/b/c/'+country+''
    input_final.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save(output_path_geof)

    # Save Master poi file
    output_path_master = 's3a://a/b/c/'+country+'/master'
    poi_final.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save(output_path_master)
    print(''+country+' Complete')
```

Result:

```
+---------+-------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|unique_id|country|latitude|longitude|radius|l1_name|l2_name|l3_name|l4_name|
+---------+-------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
+---------+-------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

+---+----+--------+---------+------+
| no|name|latitude|longitude|radius|
+---+----+--------+---------+------+
+---+----+--------+---------+------+
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why do you do this `poi_co = poi_reference.filter(F.col('country') == '+country+')` and not `poi_co = poi_reference.filter(F.col('country') == country)`? OR `Why do you do this `poi_co = poi_reference.filter(F.col('country') == '+country+')` and not `poi_co = poi_reference.filter(F.col('country') == country)` OR `poi_co = poi_reference.filter(F.col('country') == f'{country)}'`?`